# how to launch a executable in python without blocking the python execution

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, multiprocessing

In linux, I have a executable, that should be run like this:
./a.exe inputdata

I want to launch this executable in my python script, but I do not want to block the rest of the python code.

I tried soemthing like this, but

```
# launch sensor node
def launchA():
    subprocess.Popen(["Path/a.exe", inputdata])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=launchA,args=())
    p.start()
    print("sensorlaunched")
```

However, the luanchA process still blocks the print function.

What went wrong in my code? Thanks!

Comment: You've used the `.exe` extension on a Linux binary? That's heresy!

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is pure overkill: you're creating a process with `multiprocessing` to manage a process created with `subprocess`. Just use `subprocess` alone:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["Path/a.exe", inputdata])
```

Now `p` is a handle referring to the running `a.exe` process and your script can continue doing what it was doing.

Comment: I just tired "p = subprocess.Popen(["Path/a.exe", inputdata])", but it still blocks the print function... The a.exe grabs the terminal, and I do not see print("hello") function is exectuted...

Comment: @XingFan: `a.exe` and the original process write to the same terminal, but no process "grabs" it.  Having two simultaneously running processes writing to the same terminal will certainly mix the two data streams in a non-deterministic way, but that does mean the original process blocks.

Comment: I c. Thanks! But I tried to add "&" in the command,like this p = subprocess.Popen(["Path/a.exe", inputdata],"&") to release the terminal, but I still do not see the print function is executed.........

Comment: @XingFan: that `&` doesn't do anything. The fact that nothing changes means the issue is not with `subprocess`.

Comment: @XingFan: There is no such thing as "releasing the terminal".  The terminal isn't owned by any process.  And adding a random `"&"` as parameter to `Popen()` will lead to an error.